# How to change IP address on a live system?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, static-ip

I want to change the IP address persistently on a running rPi, by running a script. I tried now to change the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file and running

`sudo systemctl restart networking`

and

`sudo systemctl restart dhdpcd`

But `ip a l` still shows the old IP address (the new one is added though)

How can I change the address without needing to reboot? Of course I want to keep the new changes after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following at the end of your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file & re-start `dhcpcd` as you did before (or simply `reboot`):

```
interface wlan0
request 192.168.1.144/24
```

- the first line (`interface wlan0`) indicates what follows is only for the `wlan0` interface. If you want to apply this to `eth0`, then it would be `interface eth0`.
- use the `request` option to ask the DHCP server for the specified IPv4 address (i.e. `192.168.1.144` is only an *example*). You should specify your address in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), but it won't *necessarily* fail if you don't. Hint: If your **subnet mask** is `255.255.255.0`, the CIDR designation is `/24`.
- There are two *caveats* for the `inform` option:

  1. the IP address you `request` must be in the "pool" of dynamic addresses as defined in your DHCP server configuration.
  2. the IP address you `request` must be ***available***; i.e. not assigned to another host. You can verify this by reviewing that *active leases* in your DHCP server.